# My Models info wont appear on new page but it does on the previous one

Tags: django, django-models, django-model-field

Within my Django implementation I created a model that would show my information that I stored on the admin in the website. I managed to create the public  page to have links of name attribute within the model but when I try to do the same on the viewpara page after going to it from the links  I can't manage to get any of the attributes of the model to appear on this page and I am confused as to why.

models.py

```
class Parasite(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=100000)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='parasite_images', default='default/default.jpg', blank=True)
        
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        super(Parasite, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

views.py

```
def public(request):
      c = Parasite.objects.all()
      context = {'c': c}
      
      return render(request, 'parasites_app/public.html',context)




def view_parasite(request,parasite_name_slug):
    context_dict = {}
    try:
        parasite = Parasite.objects.get(slug=parasite_name_slug)
        context_dict['parasites'] = parasite
    except Parasite.DoesNotExist:
       context_dict['parasites'] = None
    return render(request, 'parasites_app/viewpara.html', context = context_dict)
```

urls.py

```
 path('login/', views.user_login, name='login'),
    path('logout/', views.user_logout, name='logout'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.public, name='public'),
    path('public/', views.public, name='public'),
    path('private/', views.logged_in_content, name='private'),
    path('viewpara/',views.public,name='viewpara'),
    path('public/<slug:parasite_name_slug>/',views.view_parasite, name='view_parasite'),
    path('<slug:post_name_slug>/', views.show_post, name='show_post'),
```

public.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% extends 'parasites_app/base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block content_block %}


<h1>Public Page</h1>
<h2>Information based on series of Parasites</h2>
{% for p in c %}
    <a href="{% url 'view_parasite' p.slug %}">{{p.name}}</a>
{% endfor %}


<h3>Protozoa</h3>
<p>Protozoa are microscopic, one-celled organisms that can be free-living or parasitic in nature. They are able to multiply in humans, which contributes to their survival and also permits serious infections to develop from just a single organism. Transmission of protozoa that live in a human’s intestine to another human typically occurs through a fecal-oral route (for example, contaminated food or water or person-to-person contact). Protozoa that live in the blood or tissue of humans are transmitted to other humans by an arthropod vector (for example, through the bite of a mosquito or sand fly).</p>
<p></p>
<h3>Helminths</h3>
<p>Helminths are large, multicellular organisms that are generally visible to the naked eye in their adult stages. Like protozoa, helminths can be either free-living or parasitic in nature. In their adult form, helminths cannot multiply in humans.</p>

</h2>
{% endblock %}
```

viewpara.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% extends 'parasites_app/base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block content_block %}


{% for p in c %}
    <h3>{{p.name}}</h3>
{% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: The context object in the `view_parasite` view is named `parasites` not `c` like you loop over in your template, it's also a single object so you probably don't want to loop over it

Comment: view_parasite is a view that allows for the user to use a link to get to a new page ?

Comment: is there any way of changing the view so that the image and description will appear when the page is loaded ?